# What is a plural noun to refer to a collective of people who have committed suicide?

Tags: single-word-requests

I understand there is the plural "suicides," as in "there were 43 suicides", but that doesn't feel quite right for my use-case.

Specifically, I'm having problems with the sentence "Many *suicides* had healthy long-term relationships before they committed the final self-destructive act." This just doesn't sound right.

But neither does suicidists: "Many *suicidists* had healthy long-term relationships before they committed the final self-destructive act??!" Blech.

Is "suicides" the correct plural noun for the use-case I am contemplating? What about Nihilists? Self-murderers? While self-murderers could work, it has a negative stigma associated with it, something I want to avoid.

The suffix "-ist" seems like it should/could work:

> 1. - one that performs a (specified) action *(cyclist)*:  one that makes or produces a (specified) thing *(novelist)*
>    - one that plays a (specified) musical instrument *(harpist)*
>    - one that operates a (specified) mechanical instrument or contrivance *(automobilist)*
> 2. - one that specializes in a (specified) art or science or skill (*geologist, ventriloquist*)
> 3. - one that adheres to or advocates a (specified) doctrine or system or code of behavior *(socialist, royalist, hedonist)* or that of a (specified) individual *(Calvinist, Darwinist)*

(source http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-ist)

But "suicidist" doesn't sound or feel right. *Suicideers? Suiciders? Suicidelum? Suicidators?*

"Suiciders" has potential although it sounds like a slang word.

Comment: Many *suicide victims* had healthy long-term....

Comment: Many of those committing suicide ... Beware the error of assuming that words may be coined at will by following common morphological patterns. The explanation of the meanings -ist nouns exhibit is descriptivist.

Comment: I’ve tried to format your dictionary citation in a way that makes it more readable (the options are somewhat limited with markdown). Please note, though, that you must edit your question to include where you’re quoting from—unreferenced quotes are considered plagiarism on SE sites and will result in the question being deleted.

Comment: _suicide victims_ and _victims of suicide_ and _people who commit suicide_ certainly make the point but I'm hopeful a single word exists. Citation source added.

Comment: "Suicide" is the noun for this. It isn't used very often nowadays to refer to people, so it does sound a little odd, but any neologism you invent will sound much worse.

Comment: I hope there isn't enough of a suicide movement to warrant a collective noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to use one word, "suicides" is it, but i understand your discomfort with it. It's objectifying.

Answer (score 3):

See 3 [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/suicide)
but I would suggest it it more human or caring to call them
"**people** who commit suicide"

Comment: I'm not sure about it being more human or caring, but I do think a phrase like this is used more often than just the word "suicide".

Answer (score 1):

Would "victims of suicide" be suitable?

Comment: I don't think so, as the "victim" is also the perpetrator.

Comment: I think in most cases, the victim is too emotionally distraught to qualify as a perpetrator.